# VBA Table filter and refresh

Tags: vba, excel, filter, refresh

[Manual choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND2Cn.png)Using code I modified from the internet I have gotten my table filter the date correctly, however when the button is clicked it displays no results until I manually click ok on the filter VBA applied, once I do this it displays the correct results have I missed a trick here ?

```
Sub FilterListOrTableData()

    Dim ACell As Range
    Dim ActiveCellInTable As Boolean
    Dim FilterCriteria As String
    Dim Created As String
    Dim sToday As String
    Dim sStartDate As String
    Dim dStartDate As Date
    Dim sUpperBound, sLowerBound As String


    'Check to see if the worksheet is protected.
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "This macro will not work when the worksheet is write-protected.", _
               vbOKOnly, "Filter example"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Set a reference to the ActiveCell named ACell. You can always use
    'ACell now to point to this cell, no matter where you are in the workbook.
    Set ACell = ActiveCell

    'Test to see if ACell is in a table or list. Note that by using ACell.ListObject, you
    'don't need to know the name of the table to work with it.
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveCellInTable = (ACell.ListObject.Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If the cell is in a list or table, run the code.
    If ActiveCellInTable = True Then
        'Show all data in the table or list.
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0

        'This example filters on the first column in the List/Table
        '(change the field if needed). In this case the Table starts
        'in A so Field:=1 is column A, field 2 = column B, ......
        'Use "<>" & filtercriteria if you want to exclude the criteria from the filter.
        'FilterCriteria = InputBox("What text do you want to filter on?", _
                           '       "Type in the filter item.")
      '  ACell.ListObject.Range.AutoFilter _
              '  Field:=1, _

             '  Criteria1:="=" & FilterCriteria
             'This example filters on the ActiveCell value.
'ACell.ListObject.Range.AutoFilter _
 '   Field:=ACell.Column - ACell.ListObject.Range.Cells(1).Column + 1, _
  '  Criteria1:="=" & ACell.Text

    sToday = Date
    dStartDate = DateValue(Date) - 7
    sStartDate = Str(dStartDate)

    sLowerBound = ">=" + sStartDate
    sUpperBound = "<=" + sToday

    ACell.ListObject.Range.AutoFilter Field:=89, Criteria1:=sLowerBound, _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=sLowerBound

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Else
       ' MsgBox "Select a cell in your list or table before you run the macro.", _
               'vbOKOnly, "Filter example"
    End If

End Sub
```

This is what the macro records when I do the manual option:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FTLOG").Range.AutoFilter Field:=84, Criteria1:= _
        ">=29/11/2016", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">=29/11/2016"
End Sub
```

Comment: The filter through the code is generated with a basis of the activecell. E.g., click on the line which you want to filter and run it.

Comment: Yeah for the button to work I have to select any cell in table before it will work I will change this to a set value later on, currently the code works but nothing is displayed until I click on the customer filter created by VBA, then when I click ok on that it displays all the correct results, this issue has me totally perplexed.

Comment: Can you give a few screenshots? Seems interesting

Comment: Could only add 1 screenshot so added the one of me manually going into the customer filter VBA applied when I click ok there the table goes from being empty to showing the correct results

Comment: I am sorry, I still do not get it. So, with your code you get a filter, but the data is not filtered? Try removing the `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` from the code.

Comment: That's exactly it the code produces a filter that initially does not seem to work until I go into the manual option and click ok one I do this it works fine. Also tried removing the Refresh all still not working :(

Comment: Can you record a macro of you, doing the manual option? Then post it?

Comment: Added the recorded macro at the bottom of the original

Comment: And what happens if you put this `' ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FTLOG").Range.AutoFilter Field:=84, Criteria1:= _ ">=29/11/2016", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">=29/11/2016"` just above the `End sub` of your original macro?

Comment: I get the same effect the table goes blank until I go in the filter VBA made and click ok then correct rows appear. Also thanks for your help so far been stumped for a while now

Comment: Keep on working. Try `ACell.ListObject.Range.AutoFilter` just above `End Sub`.

Comment: Just tried it, it removed all the filters from the table.

Comment: Hm something is strange. And if you write it twice? :)

Comment: Ok so put it twice now when its run the filters for each column remain but it no longer filters on the requirements above ?

Comment: Why do you think you have `Field:=89` and `Field:=84` in your two codes?

Comment: sorry that was an error on my part both should be field 89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This works:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim dToday          As Date: dToday = Date
    Dim dStartDate      As Date: dStartDate = Date - 7
    Dim dEndDate        As Date: dEndDate = Date

    Dim sLowerBound     As String
    Dim sUpperBound     As String

    dToday = Format(dToday, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dStartDate = Format(dStartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dEndDate = Format(dEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")

    sLowerBound = ">=" & CLng(dStartDate)
    sUpperBound = "<=" & CLng(dToday)

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sLowerBound, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=sUpperBound

End Sub
```

Comment: You Sir are a hero this worked a charm filters properly and pulls the correct fields through, thank you so so much :)

Comment: I will print this and will put it on my desk! :) Thanks, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

### The problem lies in the logic not the `AutoFilter`

[image]

---

### `xlOR` will show all records that meet 1 of the conditions

**Case 1:** Show this record because Condition 2 is True

- Condition 1: <kbd>1/1/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : False
- Condition 2: <kbd>1/1/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

**Case 2:** Show this record because Condition 1 and Condition 2 is True

- Condition 1: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : True
- Condition 2: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

**Case 3:** Show this record because Condition 1 and Condition 2 is True

- Condition 1: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : True
- Condition 2: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

**Case 3:** Show this record because Condition 2 is True

- Condition 1: <kbd>12/31/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : True
- Condition 2: <kbd>12/1/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

---

### `xlAND` will show all records that meet all of the conditions

**Case 1:** Hide this record because Condition 1 is False

- Condition 1: <kbd>1/1/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : False
- Condition 2: <kbd>1/1/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

**Case 2:** Show this record because Condition 1 and Condition 2 is True

- Condition 1: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : True
- Condition 2: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

**Case 3:** Hide this record because Condition 2 is False

- Condition 1: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : True
- Condition 2: <kbd>7/31/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

**Case 3:** Show this record because Condition 2 is True

- Condition 1: <kbd>12/31/2016</kbd><kbd>>=</kbd><kbd>2/1/2016</kbd> : True
- Condition 2: <kbd>12/1/2016</kbd><kbd><=</kbd><kbd>12/6/2016</kbd> : True

---

```
Sub FilterOr()
    Range("$A$5:$F$8").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & Range("StartDate"), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("Today1")
End Sub

Sub FilterAnd()
    Range("$A$5:$F$8").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & Range("StartDate"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("Today1")
End Sub
```